# How to manually create a label in Matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to compare 2 figures as follows:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

I using the function subplot() under the library Matplotlib.pylot to plot these 2 images, and the following are my codes:

```
def Plot_Labels(data,data_check):
  data = np.reshape(data,(414,507))
  #data = np.reshape(data,(414,507))
  shape = data.shape
  nan_mask = np.isnan(data_check)
  data_mask = data[~nan_mask]
  valid_data = np.empty(shape)
  valid_data[~nan_mask] = data_mask
  valid_data[nan_mask] = np.nan

  fig, axes = plt.subplots()
  im = axes.imshow(valid_data)
  bar = plt.colorbar(im)
  bar.set_label('Flood Hazard')
  plt.show()
```

However, the labels in these 2 figures are different. For example, both 4 and 5 gives the same yellow color in the 2 figures respectively. Therefore, is there any method to manually create label 5 in the second figure, so that the 2 figures become comparable?

Comment: If I try this, will the color bar go from 0 to 5? `im = axes.imshow(valid_data, vmin=0, vmax=5)`

Comment: To change the scale of the color bar in the second state, try the following code. `bar.set_ticks([np.arange(5)]);bar.set_ticklabels([np.arange(5)])`

Comment: @r-beginners Seems the first solution (im = axes.imshow(valid_data, vmin=0, vmax=5))works. Thanks a lot.